# Pop-up background overlay not extending to bottom of page

Tags: html, css, popup, overlay

Good morning everyone

I have created a pop-up that has a white overlay with 0.9 opacity. Problem is that when the user scrolls the browser while the pop-up is open, the overlay stops at what was the bottom of the screen, it doesn't extend to the bottom of the body.

This is what I have:

```
<div id="popup">
    <div class="popupdiv">
        <a class="popup" href="URL" target="_blank"></a>
        <a class="close" href="#"></a>
    </div>
</div>

<script>
    jQuery( ".close" ).click(function() {
        jQuery( "#popup" ).hide();
    });
</script>
```

and my CSS:

```
#popup {
    position: absolute;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: rgba(255,255,255,0.9);
    z-index: 500;
}

.popupdiv {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    height: 400px;
    width: 833px;
    margin-top: -200px;
    margin-left: -416px;
    background: url(imageurl);
    z-index: 510;
}

.popup {
    display: block; 
    height: 400px;
    width: 833px;
}

.popupdiv .close {
    display: block;
    height: 18px; 
    width: 18px;
    position: relative; 
    top: -380px; 
    left: 800px; 
    background-image: url(imageurl); 
    z-index: 550;
}
```

[FIDDLE HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/hs8a4ro6/1/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

May you need to set `position:fixed` for your overlay.

Position fixed sets the origin (of this object) to the top left of the browser and stays *fixed* with respect to scrolling. This behaviour is similar to the background-attachment:fixed.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment).

Comment: Can you elaborate, why this would solve the question? You can use the provided Fiddle to test it.

Comment: @Mr. Alien Yes, once :) I tried to leave a comment to the question in advance.